# How do I ignore call to void method in EasyMock

Tags: java, easymock

I have anonymous inner class added in tested class.

```
class ToTest{

    private MyManager myManager

    public void seyMyManager(MyManager myManager){
       this.myManager = myManager;
    } 

    ....
    public void doSomething(){
    ...
        myManager.addListener(new Listener(){...});
    .....  
    }
}
```

Where my manager is class from other package which is used in method to test body.

How do I ignore this addListener call?

P.S. Ignore = I do not want make any checks for calling myManager.addListener(..) methods

Comment: Pls post code, error encountered

Comment: More code pls, where does myManager come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this.

My preferred way is to be explicit about the expectations like this:

```
MyManager myManager = EasyMock.createMock(MyManager.class);
...
myManager.addListener(EasyMock.isA(Listener.class));
...
replay(myManager);
```

The important bit here is the `EasyMock.isA` that will match the expectation against an `Listener` that is passed.  I prefer this way when there's a problem elsewhere the test fails.

Alternatively you can use a *nice* mock:

```
MyManager myManager = EasyMock.createNiceMock(MyManager.class);
...
replay(myManager);
```

However, any missing expections may not cause the test to fail, which is why I don't like creating mocks this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create myManager as a nice mock http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/EasyMockSupport.html#createNiceMock(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class) or if you need it to be strict for the other parts of your test, set the expectation using "anyTimes()" http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/IExpectationSetters.html#anyTimes()